# The Binding of "this"

Tags: javascript, binding, this

I'm learning how the value of "this" binds in JavaScript. In the following example, is it correct to say that "this" binds to the getFriends() method instead of the "details" object, which is the reason this.name = "" instead of this.name = "Joe"?

```
const details = {
    name: 'Joe',
    friends: [ 'Bob', 'Alex' ],
    getFriends: function() {
        this.friends.forEach( function( friend ) {
            console.log( this.name + " is friends with " + friend );
        } );
    }
};

details.getFriends();

// Output:
// is friends with Bob
// is friends with Alex
```

As I understand from my studies, "this" does not bind one level up in the parent scope, right? That's one benefit of using arrow functions, which bind "this" to the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quoting from w3schools**

`In a method, this refers to the owner object. 
Alone, this refers to the global object.
In a function, this refers to the global object.
In a function, in strict mode, this is undefined.
In an event, this refers to the element that received the event.
Methods like call(), and apply() can refer this to any object.`

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

Comment: Great answer. That quote really explains it well, as far as all the different bindings of the "this" keyword. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

No when you run the code this way `this` is pointing to the global window object. You can `console.log` the value of `this`. To test it, you can also place a key of `my_name` on the window (don't use name, since that's used by the window). Now when you run the code, you'll see the global:

```js
const details = {
    my_name: 'Joe',
    friends: [ 'Bob', 'Alex' ],
    getFriends: function() {
        this.friends.forEach( function( friend ) {
            console.log( this.my_name + " is friends with " + friend );
        } );
    }
};
window.my_name = "What?"
details.getFriends();
```

FYI: `forEach` takes a second value that you can use to specify what `this` will be in the callback. So this works for example:

```js
const details = {
    my_name: 'Joe',
    friends: [ 'Bob', 'Alex' ],
    getFriends: function() {
        this.friends.forEach( function( friend ) {
            console.log( this.my_name + " is friends with " + friend );
        }, this ); //<-- pass this into the forEach
    }
};

details.getFriends();
```

Of course, you can always use an arrow function too.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` refers to the *current* execution context.

By default `this` in a function is set to the global context which is always the window object in a browser:

```js
function foo() {
  return this;
}

console.assert(foo() === window);
```

However when called as a constructor, the `new` operator sets `this` to an object created from the function prototype. That context is unique to each instance.

```js
function foo() {
  return this;
}

console.assert(new foo() !== window);
console.assert(new foo() !== new foo());
```

When an object has a method, the `this` in that method is that object by default:

```js
const question = {
  ask: function () {
    return this;
  }
};

console.assert(question.ask() === question);
```

Now here is why the *current* execution context matters.

If you take that method outside of its object then that method context will default to the global context:

```js
const question = {
  ask: function () {
    return this;
  }
};

const ask = question.ask;

console.assert(ask() === window);
```

To solve that problem you can use either `bind`, `call` or `apply`:

```js
const question = {
  ask: function () {
    return this;
  }
};

const ask = question.ask;

console.assert(ask.bind(question)() === question);
console.assert(ask.call(question) === question);
console.assert(ask.apply(question) === question);
```

You must have heard of arrow functions which bind `this` to the context that was available at the time the function was defined.

Previously we had to save `this` in a variable (usually called `that`) to refer to the right context. (Or use `bind`.)

```js
function foo() {
  const that = this;
  // By the time the function executes, the execution context
  // will be different even though we invoked the function
  // as a constructor.
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.assert(that !== this);
    console.assert(this === window);
  }, 100);
}

new foo();
```

That technique became deprecated with arrow functions:

```js
function foo() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.assert(this !== window);
  }, 100);
}

new foo();
```

However remember that functions are lexically scoped, so this will *not* give you the expected result:

```js
const question = {
  ask: () => {
    return this;
  }
};

console.assert(question.ask() === window);
```

Why? At the time the arrow function was defined, the only context available in the lexical scope was the global context.